# Can't import other project's component in create-react-app with craco

Tags: reactjs, webpack, craco

I'm having an issue importing a component from one React project into another. The problems seems very basic but I'm having a really hard time figuring out where the problem is and what is the exact craco configuration to achieve my goal.

**Exporting project**

I'm exporting `App`, which is a functional React component.

*src/index.js*

```
import App from "./App";
export default App;
```

I'm using craco mainly because of Tailwindcss and antd, this is the configuration file:

*craco.config.js*

```
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const WebpackBar = require("webpackbar");
const CracoAntDesignPlugin = require("craco-antd");

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new WebpackBar({ profile: true }),
      ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ openAnalyzer: false })]
        : []),
    ],
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      paths.appBuild = webpackConfig.output.path = path.resolve("dist");

      webpackConfig.output = {
        ...webpackConfig.output,
        filename: "index.bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        library: "library",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
      };

      webpackConfig.entry = path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js");

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAntDesignPlugin,
      options: {
        customizeThemeLessPath: path.join(
          __dirname,
          "./src/styles/variables.less"
        ),
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I'm using npm to publish my package and import it in the other project. This is the package.json start configuration (infos removed for privacy):

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": [company-repo-name],
  "version": "1.1.1-alpha16",
  "homepage": ".",
  "repository": [company-repo],
  "main": "dist/index.bundle.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": [company-registry]
  },
...
```

`npm run build` works as intended and generate a `index.bundle.js` inside the dist folder. I'm not sure if the problem lies here, but the file is full of minified functions and doesn't seem to export anything.

**Consumer project**

Installing the exporting project via npm works fine, and trying to import the `App` component gives me no result:

- `import App from [company-repo-name];` gives me `{}` (empty object)
- `import { App } from [company-repo-name];` gives me `undefined`

I currently don't know where the problem lies and I'm looking forward for suggestions to try out.

Comment: what does `import * as Something  from [company-repo-name];` give you?

Comment: Also an empty object @TiagoCoelho

Comment: Did you tried with import {library} from [company-repo-name]?

Comment: Yes @lissettdm, that returns undefined.

Comment: I'm trying to disable chunks right now based on this: https://floqast.com/engineering-blog/post/implementing-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-react/, lets see how this goes.

Comment: I think setting the `libraryTarget` as `commonjs2` is `webpackConfig.output` would fix the issue.

Just try `npm link` to test out the pkg locally without having to deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after days fiddling with the webpack configurations I came across [this](https://floqast.com/engineering-blog/post/implementing-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-react/) life saver article. The thing I didn't try was the first thing the article says: "Output a single bundle instead of chunks". The lines that did the trick included changing the optimization webpack configuration:

```
config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: {
      default: false,
    },
  };
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
```

After following all the steps presented in the article, I ended up with the craco webpack configuration looking like this:

```
configure: (config, { paths }) => {
  paths.appBuild = config.output.path = path.resolve("build");
  if (process.env.REACT_APP_INJECTABLE === "true") {
    config = disableChunks(config);
    config = makeInjectable(config, { paths });
  }
  return config;
}
```

`disableChunks()` was imported from a secondary file that consolidated the build in a single bundle. I also disabled the minimization so I could have more descriptive errors in my consumer project. This is `disable-chunks.js`:

```
module.exports = function disableChunks(config) {
  // Consolidate bundle instead of chunk
  // https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin
  config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: {
      default: false,
    },
  };

  // Move runtime into bundle instead of separate file
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization
  config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;

  config.optimization.minimize = false;

  // JS
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output
  config.output.filename = "main.js";

  // CSS
  // https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin
  const cssPluginIdx = config.plugins
    .map((p) => p.constructor.name)
    .indexOf("MiniCssExtractPlugin");
  if (cssPluginIdx !== -1) {
    config.plugins[cssPluginIdx].options.filename = "main.css";
  }

  return config;
};
```

The last configuration file is `make-injectable.js` that sets the output configuration. I has this configured before but decided to move it to another file for organization reasons.

```
module.exports = function makeInjectable(config, { paths }) {
  // Output a UMD module and define its name via the library key.
  // This key will be what is referenced when the hub looks for
  // the correct module to dynamically load after the bundle is
  // injected into the DOM
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output
  config.output.library = basename(process.env.npm_package_name);
  config.output.libraryTarget = "umd";

  // Set separate entry point when building the injectable lib
  // https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points
  config.entry = `${paths.appSrc}/index.injectable.js`;

  // Exclude shared dependencies to reduce bundle size
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals
  config.externals = {
    react: "react",
    "react-router-dom": "react-router-dom",
  };

  return config;
};
```

Again, the code that worked for my was basically copied from the article [Implementing a Micro-Frontend Architecture With React](https://floqast.com/engineering-blog/post/implementing-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-react/) by [J.C. Yamokoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42388/j-c-yamokoski) (if you come across this question, thank you my man).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
webpackConfig.output = {
    ...webpackConfig.output,
    ...{
      library: 'xxxxx',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp_${name}`,
    },
  }
```